# Defining __getitem__ and __setitem__ for a property in python

Tags: python, properties

I've got an object that contains a large data table called `_X`. Data examples of various lengths sit stacked end-to-end inside `_X`, and a different table I've named `_INDEX` encodes the mapping from example number -> range in `_X` where that example lives.

What I want is to define a property called `X` with `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` of its own such that I can use `X[i,j]` to access the `j`th element of the `i`th example. This is to avoid having to write confusing verbose lines like `self._X[self._INDEX[i]:self._INDEX[i+1]][j]` all over the place.

I could make a wrapper class with the right `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` and return that from my `@property` function, but I'd rather not have to do that.

Comment: What does the property actually return? The property itself doesn't need to define `__getitem__`, just the class whose instance the property returns.

Comment: That is, `foo.X[3,4]` is really `type(foo).X.fget(foo)[3,4]`; whatever `X.fget` returns is what gets indexed, not `X` itself.

Comment: If you write a function named `X` containing the one verbose line, the rest of your code simply calls `a.X(i,j)`.  Why doesn't that work?  You can't avoid writing that verbose line once.  No properties or special methods are needed.

Comment: This makes me appreciate JavaScript, where I could always just overwrite whatever methods were bound.

Comment: I don't want this to be a function, though that would effectively do the same thing. I want it to look like proper indexing to the user. This is one of several tables, and I can expose the others without any special functions. For symmetry I want this to behave just like one of those.

Answer (score 2):

Define a wrapper class first that defines the desired `__getitem__`.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, table, index):
        self.table = table
        self.index = index
    def __getitem__(self, k):
        i, j = k
        return self.table[self.index[i]:self.index[i+1]][j]
```

Then define your property

```
@property
def X(self):
    return Foo(self._X, self._INDEX)
```

Comment: Is there no cleaner way? I really don't want a whole new class. I really just want to override/intercept the `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` calls on my `._X` array. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51159611/intercepting-getitem-calls-on-an-object-attribute

Comment: You don't have *a* array; you have an object of some type that defines `__getitem__`, and that object stores objects of *another* type with its own `__getitem__`.

Comment: This doesn't really have to be a property, no? It can just be an attribute.

Comment: IIUC, the property is necessary to return a value whose type has the appropriate `__getitem__` defined, rather then the "original" value.

Comment: I mean just `self.x = Foo()`, then `obj.x[x,y]` would work, no?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Hm, I suppose so (though `Foo` still has to take `self._X` and `self._INDEX`, or just `self` itself, as arguments). I guess it's a trade-off between the memory used to keep a `Foo` instance around vs the cost of creating the `Foo` instance on demand.

Comment: @chepner I mean, the memory overhead is negligible, unless you are creating millions of instances of the class. In any case, you're still creating a `property` object, which has it's own memory overhead...

Answer (score 0):

Add a function to your class and call it instead of `__setitem__`

```
def get_(self,attr,i,j):
    Attr = getattr(self.__class__,attr).__get__(self)
    return Attr[self._INDEX[i]:self._INDEX[i+1]][j]
def set_(self,attr,i,j,value):
    Attr = getattr(self.__class__,attr).__get__(self)
    a, a[self._INDEX[i]:self._INDEX[i+1]][j] = Attr, _ = Attr, value
    getattr(self.__class__,attr).__set__(self, Attr)

element = foo.get_('X',i,j)
foo.set_('X',i,j,value)
```

The main issue is that `foo.X[i,j] = bar` calls `__get__` on the `property` instance even if you subclass it and add a `__getitem__` or `__setitem__` method. It then calls `__setitem__` on the return value. Since the return value doesn't know about the `property` instance, it can't then call its `__set__` method directly after.

Alternatively, if you're willing to do another call explicitly, you can just actually call the `__set__` method right after.

```
foo.X[self._INDEX[i]:self._INDEX[i+1]][j] = bar
foo.X = foo._X
```

The first line only modifies `foo._X` so to call the setter you have to do so explicitly.

EDIT:

If the X setter and getter force _X to be instances of this class, item assignment will mutate _X and then call the setter.

```
class List(list):
    def __init__(self, obj, attr, lst):
        self.obj = obj
        self.attr = attr
        super().__init__(lst)
    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        super().__setitem__(index, value)
        setattr(self.obj, self.attr, self)
```